# SVG sprite in image tag

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG sprite and want to use it inside `img` tag.
They work fine when I use `use` tag but I put them inside `img` tag it does not display!

HTML:

```
<img width="50" height="50" src="flags.svg#netherlands">
```

SVG sprite:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
<style>

svg.hidden {
visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<symbol id="netherlands" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve"><path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M473.655,88.276H38.345C17.167,88.276,0,105.443,0,126.621v73.471h512v-73.471  C512,105.443,494.833,88.276,473.655,88.276z"/><path style="fill:#41479B;" d="M0,385.379c0,21.177,17.167,38.345,38.345,38.345h435.31c21.177,0,38.345-17.167,38.345-38.345  v-73.471H0V385.379z"/><rect y="200.09" style="fill:#F5F5F5;" width="512" height="111.81"/>
</symbol>
<symbol id="russia" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<path style="fill:#F5F5F5;" d="M473.655,88.276H38.345C17.167,88.276,0,105.443,0,126.621v73.471h512v-73.471  C512,105.443,494.833,88.276,473.655,88.276z"/><path style="fill:#FF4B55;" d="M0,385.379c0,21.177,17.167,38.345,38.345,38.345h435.31c21.177,0,38.345-17.167,38.345-38.345  v-73.471H0V385.379z"/><rect y="200.09" style="fill:#41479B;" width="512" height="111.81"/>
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can't use it like that in image tag. Why not use the `use` tag if it works?

Comment: If you really need to use `<img>` tags you could also use fragment identifiers. See["How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work"](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work)

Answer (score 0):

The `<use>` and `<image>` tags have different and non-overlapping usages. Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#ImageElement)

> Unlike [‘use’](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseElement), the [‘image’](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html#ImageElement) element cannot reference elements within an SVG file.

`<use>` elements have the opposite text/functionality i.e. they can only reference elements within an SVG file and not a complete file (that may change but at the moment no browser supports `<use>` referencing an entire file)

Comment: If I remove the "symbol" tag and add "svg > g" tag, it works!

Comment: Sure because now it's no longer a sprite sheet but a graphic that an image can render.